# opencv 2.4.4 for android not works

Tags: android, opencv

i had followed the tutorials on OpenCV website : http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html 
to configure OpenCV for android development on eclipse IDE, I've compiled all the samples come with OpenCV and they are compiled fine with some warnings . but when i run the compiled package on the emulator it shows me an error message saying **"OpenCV was not initialised correctly. Application will be shut down"**   for example when i run the **"15 puzzle"** sample on emulator its show me the following :

[image]

**the compiler warnings :**

[image]

**logcat output**

```
03-01 18:08:32.519: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent {     act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000     cmp=org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/.Puzzle15Activity } from pid 136
03-01 18:08:32.710: I/WindowManager(61): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
03-01 18:08:32.880: I/ActivityManager(61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260     loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=15}
03-01 18:08:33.069: D/CameraBridge(509): Attr count: 3
03-01 18:08:33.089: D/JavaCameraView(509): Java camera view ctor
03-01 18:08:33.120: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc     org.opencv.engine:OpenCVEngineProcess for service org.opencv.engine/.OpenCVEngineService:     pid=525 uid=10042 gids={}
03-01 18:08:33.269: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed     org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/.Puzzle15Activity: +556ms
03-01 18:08:33.639: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 50% free 2719K/5379K, external     1625K/2137K, paused 503ms
03-01 18:08:33.858: D/CameraBridge(509): call surfaceChanged event
03-01 18:08:34.378: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 50% free 2719K/5379K,     external 1625K/2137K, paused 741ms
03-01 18:08:34.588: I/OpenCVEngine/Service(525): Service starting
03-01 18:08:34.598: I/OpenCVEngine/Service(525): Engine binder component creating
03-01 18:08:34.618: D/dalvikvm(525): Trying to load lib     /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libOpenCVEngine.so 0x40515178
03-01 18:08:34.618: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 50% free 2719K/5379K,     external 1625K/2137K, paused 229ms
03-01 18:08:34.648: D/OpenCVEngine(525): Using ARM HW detector
03-01 18:08:34.659: D/dalvikvm(525): Added shared lib     /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libOpenCVEngine.so 0x40515178
03-01 18:08:34.659: D/dalvikvm(525): No JNI_OnLoad found in      /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libOpenCVEngine.so 0x40515178, skipping init
03-01 18:08:34.659: D/dalvikvm(525): Trying to load lib     /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libOpenCVEngine_jni.so 0x40515178
03-01 18:08:34.668: D/dalvikvm(525): Added shared lib     /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libOpenCVEngine_jni.so 0x40515178
03-01 18:08:34.668: D/dalvikvm(525): No JNI_OnLoad found in     /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libOpenCVEngine_jni.so 0x40515178, skipping init
03-01 18:08:34.668: D/OpenCVEngine/JNI(525): Java_org_opencv_engine_BinderConnector_Init
03-01 18:08:34.668: I/OpenCVEngine/JNI(525): Creating new component
03-01 18:08:34.668: I/OpenCVEngine/JNI(525): New component created successfully
03-01 18:08:34.678: I/OpenCVEngine/Service(525): Service started successfully
03-01 18:08:34.678: I/OpenCVEngine/Service(525): Service onBind called for intent Intent     { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(509): Service connection created
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine::OnTransact(1,16)
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine OCVE_GET_ENGINE_VERSION request
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine::GetVersion()
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(509): Trying to get library path
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine::OnTransact(2,16)
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine OCVE_GET_LIB_PATH_BY_VERSION      request
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine::GetLibPathByVersion(2.4.3)
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCVEngine::GetLibPathByVersion(2.4.3) impl
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/OpenCVEngine(525): PackageInfo::PackageInfo: package arch ARMv5
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/JavaBasedPackageManager(525):     JavaBasedPackageManager::GetInstalledPackages() begin
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/JavaBasedPackageManager(525): GetObjectClass call
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/JavaBasedPackageManager(525): GetMethodID call
03-01 18:08:34.688: D/JavaBasedPackageManager(525): Java package manager call
03-01 18:08:34.908: D/JavaBasedPackageManager(525): Package info conversion
03-01 18:08:34.908: D/OpenCVEngine(525): PackageInfo::PackageInfo("org.opencv.engine",     "/data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib", "2.5")
03-01 18:08:34.908: D/OpenCVEngine(525): Trying to load info library     "/data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_info.so"
03-01 18:08:34.908: I/OpenCVEngine(525): OpenCV package "org.opencv.lib_v24_armv5"     revision "4.1" found
03-01 18:08:34.918: W/dalvikvm(525): JNI WARNING: 0x40530680 is not a valid JNI     reference
03-01 18:08:34.918: W/dalvikvm(525):              in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V     (DeleteLocalRef)
03-01 18:08:34.918: I/dalvikvm(525): "Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=7 RUNNABLE
03-01 18:08:34.918: I/dalvikvm(525):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510908     self=0x116d20
03-01 18:08:34.918: I/dalvikvm(525):   | sysTid=531 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default     handle=1145392
03-01 18:08:34.918: I/dalvikvm(525):   | schedstat=( 105702049 76397389 24 )
03-01 18:08:34.918: I/dalvikvm(525):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-01 18:08:34.918: E/dalvikvm(525): VM aborting
03-01 18:08:35.052: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(136): showStatusIcon on inactive     InputConnection
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***     *** ***
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint:     'generic/google_sdk/generic:2.3.4/GINGERBREAD/123630:eng/test-keys'
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31): pid: 525, tid: 531  >>>     org.opencv.engine:OpenCVEngineProcess <<<
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr     deadd00d
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31):  r0 fffffec4  r1 deadd00d  r2 00000026  r3 00000000
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31):  r4 800a45c0  r5 800857c4  r6 800857c4  r7 43db2c10
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31):  r8 00000000  r9 40530680  10 00000020  fp 002987a8
03-01 18:08:35.058: I/DEBUG(31):  ip 800a4720  sp 43db2a28  lr afd19375  pc 80045a4a      cpsr 20000030
03-01 18:08:35.288: I/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00045a4a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.288: I/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 00037748  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.288: I/DEBUG(31):          #02  pc 000386ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.298: I/DEBUG(31):          #03  pc 0003871e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.298: I/DEBUG(31):          #04  pc 00039236  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.298: I/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
03-01 18:08:35.308: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a28 447a4479 ed0cf7d1 20004c09 ee34f7d1 
03-01 18:08:35.308: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a38 447c4808 6bdb5823 d0002b00 49064798 
03-01 18:08:35.308: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a48 700a2226 eea0f7d1 000436b7 00045275 
03-01 18:08:35.308: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a58 0005eb82 fffffec4 deadd00d b510b40e 
03-01 18:08:35.328: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a68 4c0a4b09 447bb083 aa05591b 6b5bca02 
03-01 18:08:35.328: I/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
03-01 18:08:35.328: I/DEBUG(31): afd19354 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
03-01 18:08:35.328: I/DEBUG(31): afd19364 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
03-01 18:08:35.338: I/DEBUG(31): afd19374 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
03-01 18:08:35.338: I/DEBUG(31): afd19384 bdf01c30 000281a8 ffffff88 1c0fb5f0 
03-01 18:08:35.338: I/DEBUG(31): afd19394 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
03-01 18:08:35.338: I/DEBUG(31): stack:
03-01 18:08:35.338: I/DEBUG(31):     43db29e8  00000015  
03-01 18:08:35.338: I/DEBUG(31):     43db29ec  afd18407  /system/lib/libc.so
03-01 18:08:35.348: I/DEBUG(31):     43db29f0  afd4270c  /system/lib/libc.so
03-01 18:08:35.348: I/DEBUG(31):     43db29f4  afd426b8  /system/lib/libc.so
03-01 18:08:35.348: I/DEBUG(31):     43db29f8  00000000  
03-01 18:08:35.348: I/DEBUG(31):     43db29fc  afd19375  /system/lib/libc.so
03-01 18:08:35.348: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a00  00116d20  [heap]
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a04  afd183d9  /system/lib/libc.so
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a08  43db2c10  
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a0c  0005eb82  [heap]
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a10  800857c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a14  800857c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a18  43db2c10  
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a1c  afd18437  /system/lib/libc.so
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a20  df002777  
03-01 18:08:35.358: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a24  e3a070ad  
03-01 18:08:35.368: I/DEBUG(31): #00 43db2a28  40530680  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap      (deleted)
03-01 18:08:35.368: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a2c  8003774d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:35.368: I/DEBUG(31): #01 43db2a30  40530680  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap     (deleted)
03-01 18:08:35.368: I/DEBUG(31):     43db2a34  800386f1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-01 18:08:36.498: D/dalvikvm(61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 45K, 45% free 4987K/9031K,     external 3897K/4867K, paused 196ms
03-01 18:08:37.318: I/BootReceiver(61): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox     (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-01 18:08:37.378: D/Zygote(33): Process 525 terminated by signal (11)
03-01 18:08:37.419: I/ActivityManager(61): Process org.opencv.engine:OpenCVEngineProcess      (pid 525) has died.
03-01 18:08:37.419: W/ActivityManager(61): Scheduling restart of crashed service     org.opencv.engine/.OpenCVEngineService in 5000ms
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509): android.os.DeadObjectException
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native     Method)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at     org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface$Stub$Proxy.getLibPathByVersion(OpenCVEngineInterface    .java:137)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at      org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:182)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at     android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1064)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at     android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1081)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-01 18:08:37.428: W/System.err(509):  at      android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-01 18:08:37.448: W/System.err(509):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 18:08:37.448: W/System.err(509):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-01 18:08:37.448: W/System.err(509):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-01 18:08:37.448: W/System.err(509):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-01 18:08:37.448: W/System.err(509):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native       Method)
03-01 18:08:37.458: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(509): Init finished with status 255
03-01 18:08:37.458: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(509): Unbind from service
03-01 18:08:37.458: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(509): Calling using callback
03-01 18:08:37.458: E/OpenCVLoader/BaseLoaderCallback(509): OpenCV loading failed!
03-01 18:08:37.728: D/dalvikvm(509): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 137K, 49% free 2785K/5379K,     external 2050K/2137K, paused 183ms
03-01 18:08:43.148: I/WindowManager(61): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
03-01 18:08:43.168: I/ActivityManager(61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260        loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=16}
03-01 18:08:45.288: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(509): showStatusIcon on inactive     InputConnection
```

i'am using **OpenCV 2.4.4 beta for android** ,

**eclipse 4.2.1 juno** ,

**Windows 6 x64 bit as development platform**  ,

and the emulator targeted **Google API 11** which is the same used when iv'e built the samples project

and i have also installed the android mangaer **OpenCV_2.4.4_Manager_2.5_armeabi.apk** on the emulator.

**any suggestion , thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Try the 2.4.4 release package that has just been released.
(http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.4/OpenCV-2.4.4-android-sdk.zip/download)

Answer (score 0):

try install last OpenCV Manager(2.6). Often, the emulator does not work quite the way on a real device... What the configuration of your emulator?

Answer (score 0):

For OpenCv4Android from OpenCV 2.4.4 onwards, it has become mandatory to install OpenCV Manager, prior to running any OpenCv-Android application.